# I am still confused about have or has

Tags: grammatical-number

This is the sentence:

> "... Has established a committee who has/have been appointed as the custodians of ..."

Do I use *has* or *have*?
Do I use *custodian* or *custodians*?

Answer (score 1):

A committee is a singular object (not the the individuals within it) so your sentence would be better as

> .... has established a committee **which has** been appointed as the
>   **custodian** of ...

I think you could use **that has** instead of **which has** if you prefer.

Comment: For comparison: "... has selected committee members who have been been appointed custodians of..."

The committee is one thing. The members of the committee are (presumably) more than one.